# Leave Approval By Various Number of Managers odoo

Tags: odoo-8

I need to Approve Leaves of Employees,by 3 level in odoo i have 2 level approve

but my need is 
1.direct manager 
2.HR 
3.by CEO final approve how can i do it in odoo?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Manager in Employee like ABC employee is having a manager as BCD. BCD is having a manger as CDE and CDE is having a manager as DEF. Here BCD is a direct manager, CDE is HR and DEF is CEO. It should go for searching a manager at the top. I am not sure about your exact requirements otherwise I can also suggest you to go by configuring Departments as Each Department is having a Parent Department.

Comment: After submit a leave by employee it has approve by 3 levels when you give approve button status change to second approve after that when u select validate employee leave is approved but i need a final approve after the validation of HR .after HR approve leave state need to show CEO approval is waiting .